# Valid signing identity not found no ice what's wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

To connect my device to this developer profile, I tried to make this steps:

I added the iPhone in the section "Device"
I clicked on the section "Provisioning Profiles"
I clicked on the button "+"
I choose the kind of certificate I need (iOS App Development)
I choose an App ID
I choose the certificate
I downloaded the file generated
I clicked on this file and it open Xcode Organizer
Here I'm having issue: when I go to Organizer -> Provisioning Profile, I see the profile I generated, but it says "Valid signing identity not found". What's wrong with my steps?

Here's the pic in which you can see my issue:

[image]

Comment: Check if your build setting to see how you signed your code. Make sure you selected iPhone Distribution instead of iPhone Developer

Comment: Did you renew your old developer subscription on last days?

Comment: The profile expire 03 march 2014...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because your private signing key is not in your Mac's Keychain. At some point you created a public/private key pair and committed it to Apple through the provisioning portal in iOS Dev center. If you still have the private key in another computer you can move it to your current computer using Keychains export/import functions. Another option is to create a new private/public key pair.